# How do I set the value of my field so that I can call it from another class?

Tags: java, field

I have the following code here. I need to call the meterNumber field from my main class but as you can see it's null. I need it to take the value of the meterNumber is the load method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Meter {

   public static MeterNumber meterNumber;

   private Tariff[] tariffs;

   public Meter(MeterNumber meterNumber, Tariff[] tariffs) {
      this.meterNumber = meterNumber;
      this.tariffs = tariffs;
   }

   public static Meter load(Scanner sc) {
       MeterNumber meterNumber = MeterNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine());
       int n = sc.nextInt();
       Tariff[] tariffs = new Tariff[n];
       String kind = sc.next();
       while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
       sc.nextLine();
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         //String kind = sc.next();
         //sc.nextLine();
         if (kind.equals("P")) {
            tariffs[i] = PeakTariff.PEAK_TARIFF;
         } else if (kind.equals("O")) {
            tariffs[i] = OffPeakTariff.OFF_PEAK_TARIFF;
         } 
      }
   }
   return new Meter(meterNumber, tariffs);
}

   public MeterNumber getMeterNumber() {
      return meterNumber;
   }

}
```

I don't want to use the getter method because I am thinking that would require me to create an instance of the class first.

Comment: What isn't working for you here?

Comment: for instance, when i call System.out.println(Meter.meterNumber); from my main method, it returns null. Like I said i want it to have a meterNumber value from the load method

Comment: You need to include your main method. Also, I've addressed some of the significant difficulties with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought as to why you're getting null from meterNumber is probably that you haven't given it a value yet. If you just define a variable as `public Type x` without initializing it, its value will be null. Are you assigning it a value before you call `System.out.println(Meter.meterNumber)`?

But as far as the rest of the code, there are some significant issues. One of them is that you're weirdly mixing the concept of static and instance here.

You have a class you instantiate - `Meter` - with a static member `meterNumber`. This means that each time you instantiate a new `Meter`, the `meterNumber` for every single instance of `Meter` is going to change, and they're all going to reflect the most recent value. If a meter number is something that belongs logically and individually to each meter, it needs to be an instance member. If it's something that's identical between every member, either use a static function to set it once (if it's unknown to you, and needs to be provided by a user) or change the field to an instance member (if it's different for each one). Don't set a static field within a constructor of a non-singleton. (Or at all, really.)

Also, you set the `meterNumber` field in the instance constructor for the `Meter` class, but then you set it again in the `load` method. Which, by the way, returns a `Meter` object - what's the point in having a static method that performs functions that should either exist outside the class (Why have a `Meter` be responsible for scanning input from the user? How does that relate to the function or the encapsulation of the object?) or within the constructor.

Lastly, you have a method, `getMeterNumber`, that performs no real function at all. `meterNumber` is a public field - what's the point in having a function that ends up doing the same thing as just referencing meterNumber, and what's the point in allowing both?

To fix all this, firstly I'd change `meterNumber` from `public static` to just `public`. Secondly, I'd would move all the logic of load() into a method outside the `Meter` object. A `Meter` doesn't need to know how it's made, or how to talk to the user. What it needs to know is what its number is and what its tariffs are, so don't give it more knowledge or responsibility than that. Ask the user what the meter number is, then ask what all the tariffs are, then pass those values to the `Meter()` constructor.

Comment: hey furkle thanks, am a bit confused. But what if I make the meterNumber variable both non-static and a private. Because I tried that as well. Was giving some other errors.

Comment: @lolian I've provided further guidance in a new edit. Let me know if there's anything you're confused about.

Comment: K, I will let me just go over your answer. Thank you for your time

Comment: @lolian If my answer helped you out, please don't forget to use the check mark to select it.

Comment: hey thanks. still working on it but your explanation give me a lot of insight.